# Grok Pattern for Timestamp

Tags: grok

I have a logfile with timestamp as follows
Tue, 18 Jul 2017 02:39:45 GMT

What can be the Gork pattern for this
I have tried: %{DATESTAMP_RFC2822: timestamp}

But it says not matched in http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a custom pattern for this:

```
(?<date>%{DAY}, %{MONTHDAY} %{MONTH} %{YEAR} %{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND} GMT)
```

This will match the entire string you provided in a single field called `date`. Note tough that there is no pattern for the GMT timezone so you either hardcode it, or create a custom pattern yourself there.